# strcpy : Implementation method

Tags: c, string

I was going through a possible implementation method for library function `strcpy`. It is :

```
void strcpy(char *src, char *dest)
{
while (*dest++ = *src++)
            ;
}
```

How can this possibly work without check of `'\0'` ??

Comment: If *src =="\0" it is gonna end up the while. Isn't it ?

Comment: You switched the variables to be right, but for the standard library the arguments are supposed to be in the order `dest, src`. This is how they do it for `strcpy`, `strcat`, `memcpy`, `memmove`, and so on.

Comment: Also, you should make `src` a `const char *` to indicate that it won't be written to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `*dest++ = *src++` is the value of `*src` before the increment of `src`. If this value is `\0`, the loop terminates.