# Cleaner way to remove a substring from str in C

Tags: c, string, substring, memmove

I have the following string `ID is a sample string remove to /0.10`, I would like to end up with the following: `ID/0.10`.

This is what I came up with. However, I'm looking for a cleaner/nicer way of doing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] = "ID is a sample string remove to /0.10";
    char *a = strstr(str, "ID");
    char *b = strrchr (str, '/');
    if (a == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (b == NULL)
        return 0;

    int p1 = a-str+2;
    int p2 = b-str;
    int remL = p2 - p1;
    int until = (strlen(str) - p1 - remL) +1;

    memmove (str+p1, str+(p1+remL), until);
    printf ("%s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After determining `a` and `b` you can simplify the `memmove` like this:

```
char str[] = "ID is a sample string remove to /0.10";
char *a = strstr(str, "ID");
char *b = strrchr (str, '/');
if ((a == NULL) || (b == NULL) || (b < a))
    return 0;

memmove(a+2, b, strlen(b)+1);
```

The calculations you do on the string lengths are not really necessary.

Comment: Excessive calculation of length in this version.

Comment: Please fix redundant bracket at the end of `memmove()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
 char str[] = "ID is a sample string remove to /0.10";
 char *a = strstr(str, "ID");
 char *b = strrchr (str, '/');
 if (a == NULL || b == NULL)
    return 0;
 int dist = b - a; 
 if (dist <= 0) return 0;  // aware "/ ID"

 a += 2;
 while (*a ++ = *b ++);

 printf ("%s\n",str);

 return 0;
}
```

Or if you like a very dense version

```
 char str[] = "ID is a sample string remove to /0.10";
 char *a = strstr(str, "ID");
 char *b = strrchr (str, '/');
 if (a == NULL || b < a) return 0; // no need to test b against NULL, implied with <
 a ++;
 while (*(++ a) = *b ++);
```

Comment: Are you sure that behavior of `while (*a ++ = *b ++);` is defined by C standard?

Comment: I am quite sure that early implementations of strcpy using that fragment. Where do you see a problem? (OK, you have to ignore the warning) (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962159/strcpy-implementation-method)

Comment: Without the spaces, it is actually the K&R strcpy(): `while (*a++ = *b++);`.

Comment: @stefanbachert, seems like it's ok.