# strcpy using pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to write strcpy on my own using pointers and I get an error during runtime.

```
void str_cpy(char **destination, const char *source) {
//    char *s1 = *destination;

   while (*source != '\0') {
      **destination++ = *source++; //Get an error here
   }
   **destination = '\0';
}
```

I call the function as follows:

```
char *str = NULL;
str_cpy(&str, "String");
```

Is it not OK?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a double pointer for destination?

Comment: Why are you copying your string to a NULL?

Comment: @axiom: This is an assignment so I can't change the main().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not okay. Why? Because `str` is a `NULL` pointer. It's pointing to nothing. When you try to write values into it, where will they go? It's not pointing to any allocated memory!

You first have to allocate memory for `str`. You can do:

```
char *str = malloc(strlen("String") + 1); // + 1 for the '\0' character at the end of C-style strings
```

Or you can do:

```
char str[256]; // make str large enough to hold 256 chars. Note that this is not as safe as the above version!
```

Also, `destination` should be a single pointer, not a double pointer. Well, it's not technically wrong to use a double pointer, it's just unnecessary.

Optionally, you can allocate the memory in the `str_cpy` function, like so:

```
void str_cpy(char **destination, const char *source) {
    *destination = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);
    // ... continue as normal
```

Comment: The problem is it's an assignment and I can't change my main, so I can't allocate memory before passing str to the function.

Comment: @user1836819:  Then allocate the memory in `str_cpy`. I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks, after I have made the change it was OK but when I try to execute the code I mentioned earlier,  **destination++ = *source++, it does not increment the variables correctly. It increments the address but not the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For simplicity's sake, this can be done in one line in a function.

```
void mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src) {
  while (*dest++ = *src++);
}
```

This being said, you do need to allocate memory for `dest` beforehand using `malloc` or just simply by having a character array like `char dest[256]`.

Comment: Could you please explain why testing for the terminating `\0` is not necessary?

Comment: Okay, see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962159/strcpy-implementation-method)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any need to pass a pointer-to-pointer:

```
void str_cpy(char *dst, const char *src) {
   while (*src != '\0') {
      *dst++ = *src++; 
   }
   *dst = '\0';
}
```

And you need to allocate memory for `dst` before passing:

```
const char *src = "String";
char *str = malloc(strlen(src)+1); //plus one for null byte
str_cpy(dst, src);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should likely allocate some memory for that pointer before passing it off to a function that fills what it points *to* (which in this case, is NULL).

Example:

```
char *str = malloc(128);
if (str)
{
   str_cpy(&str, "String");
   free(str);
   str = NULL;
}
```

I advise not doing this without also providing target-buffer size information (i.e. if you're writing your own, then boundary-check the target buffer, otherwise your version has the same security flaws as `strcpy()` which are bad enough as it is).

Note: Unless you're planning on changing the address held by the pointer passed as the target, you need not use a double pointer either. The double pointer usage you have prevents the traditional `strcpy()` usage pattern of:

```
char str[128];
str_cpy(&str, "Hello"); // error.
```

An array address cannot be passed as a pointer-to-pointer, so your code cannot fill a static array without an intermediate pointer:

```
char str[128];
char *p = str;
str_cpy(&p, "Hello");  //ok. passing address of pointer.
```

If this is not intentional (and I don't see why it could be unless you have ideas of internally emulating `strdup()` on a NULL pointer passage) You should address this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete implementation.
Good article from here. Describes timing and performance. I did not measure myself though.
http://www.howstuffworks.com/c35.htm

```
char* mystrcpy(char *dst, const char *src) {
char *ptr = dst;
while ((*dst++ = *src++) ) ;
return ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
const char *src = "This is C.\0";
char *dst = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(src)+1)); //+1 for the null character
dst = mystrcpy(dst, src);
printf("%s",dst);
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced same problem of above one using `double pointer strcpy implementation`

It might helpful to others below code

```
 void strcpy_i( char **dst, const char *src )
 {
    *dst=(char *)malloc((strlen(src)+1)*sizeof(char));

    char *tmp=*dst;

    if(tmp == NULL || src == NULL)
    return ;

    while((*tmp++=*src++)!='\0');
}

int main()
{
    char v[]="Vinay Hunachyal";
    char *d=NULL;

    strcpy_i(&d,v);
    printf("%s",d);

 return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{

    void mystrcpy(char *,char *);

    char s1[100],s2[100];
    char *p1;
    char *p2;
    p1=s1;
    p2=s2;
    printf("Enter the string to copy to s2...?\n");
    scanf("%s",p1);


    mystrcpy(p2,p1);

    printf("S2 after copying = %s",p2);

}
void mystrcpy(char *p2,char *p1)
{
    while(*p1!='\0')
    {
        *p2=*p1;
        p2++;
        p1++;
    }
    *p2='\0';

}
```

Its my solution..**Simple to understand**..