# strcopy function using pointers not working

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

I need to make a function that receives two char pointers and copies the contents of one into the other, and then returns the beginning of the pointer. I have been messing with this for a couple hours now and have read 100 examples that are all different. Here is what I have right now:

```
char * mystrcpy(char * dest, char * src) {
        while(1) {
          if(*src == '\0') {
            *dest = '\0';
            return dest;
          }
          else {
            *dest = *src;
            *src++;
            *dest++;
          }
        }
```

Comment: You're incrementing chars instead of the pointers that point to them, and failing to keep track of the beginning of the destination string. **Try some simpler exercises first.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460934/strcpy-using-pointers/26317153#26317153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dest++;
```

`dest` is a pointer and you are moving it in order to copy values from `src`
So when you return `dest` it is already pointing to end of the string.

So don't move this pointer just copy values to it using indexing.

```
int i=0;
while( *src)
{
    dest[i] = *src;
    i++;
    src++;
}

dest[i] = '\0';

return dest;
```

So even if you fix `*dest++` to `dest++` what you return will not give the expected results.

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

What you want is to increment the pointers, while you actually increment the character that they point to.

Change

```
*src++;
*dest++;
```

to:

```
src++;
dest++;
```

Comment: After doing that, what I am returning still does not give me the right output. For example, if i were to give a src as "Hello world" it is returning ""

Comment: @Cory You are moving your pointer which is wrong in-order to return the value

Answer (score 0):

these two lines:

```
    *src++;
    *dest++;
```

should be:

```
    src++;
    dest++;
```

Notice no de-reference of the pointers as the code needs to increment the pointers, not what the pointers are pointing to.

And it would be a good idea to save the initial value of dest, so it can be returned.  And to avoid losing any string already in the dest buffer, I suspect the value (after saving) of dest needs to be incremented by dest += strlen(dest);

so a concentation of the two strings occurs rather than overlaying the initial string in dest.

Before that function is called, there should be a check that the dest buffer is long enough to hold the strlen() of both strings +1.

+1 is to allow for the termination byte.