# implementing a strcpy() function without using <string.h> in C

Tags: c, strcpy

My task is like this: I should implement the strcpy function under the following constraints:

1. The function should use pointer expression (`*(d+i)`)
2. I should implement it without using `<string.h>`

I'm programming in Visual Studio 2019.
I searched some source code in google and run them, but my program has a logical error. The program ends right away, each time. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Here's my code in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows. Please tell me what's wrong.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void strcpy(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    char* sen1 = "Hello";
    char* sen2 = "Friends";

    strcpy(sen1, sen2);

    printf("The result: %s\n", sen1);

    return 0;
}

void strcpy(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*(str2 + i) != '\0')
    {
        *(str1 + i) = *(str2 + i);
        i++;
    }
    *(str1 + i) = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... What *writable* storage do `sen1` and `sen2` point to? (or are they simply pointers initialized pointing to non-modifiable *String Literals*?) Why not, e.g. `char sen1[64] = "Hello"; char sen2[64] = "Friends";` so both are declared as *arrays*?

Comment: The program hasn't to scan strings and assign sen1 and sen2. So I set up String Literals to them.
(And I'm not good at English... So please be kind to understand!)

Comment: Sure, you can simulate your *source* (`sen2`) string with a string literal for testing, but your pointer for `sen1` must point to valid storage that you can write to (like a character array long enough to hold `sen1` (plus the nul-terminating character).

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of [strcpy using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460934/strcpy-using-pointers)

Comment: @Abra Almost, but not quite. The requirement about avoiding index and using ptr+offset notation makes it sufficiently different, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to needing to provide writable storage for `sen1`, you should also check to ensure `str2 != NULL` in your function before dereferencing `str2` (otherwise, even if you fix all other errors -- a segfault will likely result)

For example, in your code you can define a constant to use in setting the size of a `sen1` *array* (or you can allocate storage with `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` -- save that for later). Using an array you can do, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXC 64     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
int main (void)
{
    char sen1[MAXC] = "Hello";
    char *sen2 = "Friends";

    mystrcpy (sen1, sen2);

    printf ("The result: %s\n", sen1);

}
```

In your strcpy function, check that `str2` isn't `NULL` before using `str2` in your function, e.g.

```
char *mystrcpy (char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *p = dest;

    if (!src || !dest) {            /* ensure src or dest is not NULL */
        fputs ("error: src or dest parameters NULL in mystrcpy().\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    do                              /* loop */
        *p++ = *src;                /* copy each char in src to dest */
    while (*src++);                 /* (including the nul-termianting char) */

    return dest;                    /* return pointer to dest */
}
```

Now you will copy your source string to your destination string in your (renamed) `mystrcpy()` function, receiving the results you expect:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/mystrcpy
The result: Friends
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I'm not sure if the test ensuring `src` is not NULL is a good idea. If `src` is NULL I'd let the program crash (which will happen on almost all present desktop platforms). I don't think that _actual_ `strcpy` implementation do this check.

Comment: That's more a check/habit in all functions that take pointers as arguments before dereferencing. You have a good point. An `if (!src) { fputs ("error: NULL source pointer in mystrcpy().\n", stderr); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }` would be cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: There are some things I haven't learned yet(exit, fputs(maybe a role of printf?)), so I'll have to refer to some of them. But thanks for your kind comment!

Comment: @올리브한개 `exit` is used to stop executing the program from inside of the function. `fputs()` is just a alternative to the `printf()` function especially for printing strings only and in this case exclusive to the error stream `stderr` instead of `stdout` as it is with `printf`.

Comment: I added `#include <stdlib.h>` which provides the `exit()` function that allows you to gracefully exit your program from within a function without returning to `main()`. There are only two codes `EXIT_SUCCESS` (value `0`) and `EXIT_FAULURE` (value `1`). `fputs()` is just `puts()` that allows you to output a string to any file (rather than just to `stdout` as `puts()` and `printf()` due by default). You would use `fprintf()` if you required conversions within your *format string*, otherwise, you compile likely substitutes `puts()/fputs()` for you.

Comment: I think it would be useful to also check `dest` for being a `NULL` pointer. If it is, one would write to undefined memory. Also why did you implemented `p`? It seems redundant.

Comment: Good call on checking `dest` not `NULL` also. `p` allows me to `return dest;`, otherwise the pointer `dest` would be at the end of the string if I was increment it.

Comment: Oh, I fully understand. I think I can use the functions thanks to you. Thank you for your detailed answer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Two problems, at least:

1. String literals are not writable in C. Often the symptom is a crash (SIGSEGV).
2. You are not allowed to use the identifier `strcpy` for your own function. Use another name.

Three clean code issues, at least:

1. Turn `int main()` into `int main(void)` to make it properly typed.
2. `str1` and `str2` are too generic names. They don't indicate which is the source and which is the destination pointer. What about `my_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)`?
3. I'd use `size_t i` for the index counter instead of `int`, because that's the type all the string length functions and the `sizeof` operator return. It's also an unsigned type and can copy *really* long strings :-) The `size_t` is available after `#include <stddef.h>`.

Comment: (well qualified, at minimum `:)`

Comment: 1. Then should I scan string literals for sen1 and sen2?
2. Do I use another name such as 'mystrcpy'?
(And I'm not good at English... So please be kind to understand!)

Comment: @올리브한개 1. No, only the destination needs to be an array, like `char dest[64];`. But it's ok to make both an array. 2. Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your help!!! I solved my problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: @올리브한개 Wonderful! The next step on Stackoverflow is to *accept* the answer that helped you most by clicking the check mark to the left. It's okay to wait a day or two for more answers to appear.

Comment: @Jens Okay! Thanks for explaining. I'd like to know other ways, so I'll put it off a little bit. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
...
char* source = "Hello";
// or char source[] = "Hello";
char destination[1000];      // destination buffer long enough for playing around

my_strcpy(destination, source);

printf("%s\n", destination);   // should print "Hello" if my_strcpy is corect
...
```

For the rest read Jens's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Among the other good answers, just regarding the implementation of your `strcpy` function and not a detailed issue analyze of your actual code, another approach is this:

```
char * n_strcpy(char * dest, char const * src)
{
    if (dest == NULL || src == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *ptr = dest;

    while ((*dest++ = *src++));

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: I did this way, but the error kept happening. However I know that the problem is main() function right now. Thanks!

Comment: This can't possibly work. You're incrementing possibly uninitialized data and const-qualified data. Please test code before posting. And the requirements explicitly stated to not use index notation.

Comment: @Jens You was right, me fool. Corrected. But I don´t understand where you trying to point me at with uninitialized data. Do you mean `src`/`dest` itself or `*src` `*dest`, or even `ptr`?

Comment: Because of `dest[i]++`, since dest[] may be uninitialized in the call and you increment each uninitialized character.